# Can a C# solution have multiple forms, but have one selected to be the main when compiled?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

Basically, this program I want to have a common backend, but have it so I can compile it with a different GUI to control the program.  I know that I can make multiple forms, but is there a way to tell the solution to compile, and say that Form1 is the GUI, and then later, compile it and tell it that `Form2` is the GUI (and to not include `Form1` in the compiled program).

`Form1` will be more for an administrator with more features, while the `Form2` will be for a normal user with far less capabilities than the `Form1`.  Is this possible, or do I just have to make a new solution?

Comment: doesnt every win form applicatin start with opening a specific form?

Comment: Does it need to be compiled a certain way?  Could you get away with an application setting to control the default form instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use [conditional compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and exclude code from the compile entirely. So you can do something similar to:

```
#if USER_GUI

public class BasicForm : Form
{
  // ...
}

#endif
```

and

```
#if ADMIN_GUI

public class AdvancedForm : Form
{
  // ...
}

#endif
```

then have a similar `#ifdef` when starting the GUI to call the approriate constructor

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // ...

    #if USER_GUI
    var form = new UserForm()
    #endif

    #if ADMIN_GUI
    var form = new AdvancedForm()
    #endif

    Application.Run(form);
}
```

When you compile, you can set the project properties with the appropriate variable in Project -> Properties -> Build -> Conditional compilation symbols, and add either USER_GUI or ADMIN_GUI

Comment: How will it know which user role is executing the app?

Comment: There is no way to *not have both forms compiled in* (as requested in the question), and also dynamically select the role type. The way I have said will let you **build** a GUI with **only** one form

Comment: Not being able to dynamically select role type, IE a login, isn't very efficient. You'd have to compile and deploy and maintain 2 versions.

Comment: The question explicitly asked that the alternate form should not be compiled in. If the intention was to dynamically select the form to view at runtime, then a simple `if` condition could be used to select the form after checking entitlements or command-line arguments, and not have any of the conditional compilation I mentioned

Comment: Nichromium and jglouie are correct, I wanted it to not be compiled into the program.  And while it isn't ideal to maintain 2 versions, most of the work is done by another class that both reference, and the user GUI is going to be pretty simple, so it won't need much maintenance in comparison to the admin one.  One thing on nichromium's though, when trying this out, I found that #ifdef isn't in C# (at least not mine, heh), you have to just use #if.  I should have thought of this, but I am still rather new to C#, and kind of forgot about using preprocessor commands in C#.  Thanks

Comment: Ah! You are correct. I was getting my languages confused :) It is indeed `#if`. I've updated my answer to reflect this in case I confuse future stackoverflower's

Comment: @nichromium +1 for knowing conditional compilation

Answer (score 3):

Preprocessor conditionals come to mind.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk(VS.71).aspx

```
Form form;
#if USE_FORM_1
form = new Form1();
#else
form = new Form2();
#endif
```

Compile it once with `USE_FORM_1` defined, and once without it defined.

NOTE: I somewhat wonder whether this should be compiled into the app.  You could also compile once, and use an `app.config` setting to say what the default form should be.

Answer (score 2):

There are a several ways to achieve this. Here's a couple

If you are having the user log in first, then you can check the role and either

1. Display role specific form
2. Have one form with hidden role specific controls

This goes on the assumption that because you have mentioned different roles. Not sure how you are going about that.'

If you are having the user log in first then the Login from is actually your default form that runs at app start. From there you can create new instance of `AdminForm` or `StandardUserForm` or just load one form toggle a panel on the form, one with Admin function, the other without.